# Error with updating user group

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement user blocking function on my site but there's a problem with query updating and I can't see what's the main reason. Error reporting is ON (E_ALL) and everything else works (registration, login, finding users, name updating), except group updating.

```
if (Input::exists()) {
    if (isset($_POST['block-username'])) {
        $banUser = Input::get('ban');
        if(!empty($banUser)) {
            if ($user->find($banUser) == false) {
                echo "That user doesn't exists.";
            } else {
                try {
                    $user->update(array('group' => 4));

                    echo 'User {$user->data()->username} is blocked.';
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());          
                }                                   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the update function:

```
/** 
 * Update in database
 *
 * @param string $table
 * @param int    $id
 * @param array  $fields
 * @return bool
 */
public function update($table, $id, array $fields) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;
    $countFields = count($fields);

    foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if ($x < $countFields) {
            $set .= ',';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE ID = {$id}";
    if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, updating works with name:

```
try {
    $user->update(array('name' => Input::get('name')));

    Session::flash('home', 'Your details have been updated.');
    Redirect::to('index.php');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());  
}
```

I've checked connection with database, included files and MySQL permissions. I just get message `There was a problem updating`.

UPDATE: This is what I get with `print_r($e);` before `die($e->getMessage());`:

```
Exception Object ( [message:protected] => There was a problem updating 
                   [string:Exception:private] => 
                          [code:protected] => 0 
                          [file:protected] => /home/nikola/public_html/matehub/classes/User.php 
                          [line:protected] => 52 
                          [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( 
                                [0] => Array ( 
                                       [file] => /home/nikola/public_html/matehub/admin.php 
                                       [line] => 113 
                                       [function] => update 
                                       [class] => User 
                                       [type] => -> 
                                       [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [group] => 4 ) 
                                       ) 
                                 )
                          ) 
                          [previous:Exception:private] => )
```

Answer (score 0):

print the sql inside your database update function.

```
public function update($table, $id, array $fields) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;
    $countFields = count($fields);

    foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if ($x < $countFields) {
            $set .= ',';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE ID = {$id}";

    echo $sql; //here

    if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then it will be user to debug.

try this query exactly the way i wrote:

```
UPDATE  `users` SET  `group` =  '4' WHERE  `users`.`id` =32;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87077/discussion-on-answer-by-hmtareque-error-with-updating-user-group-solved).